# Minimal requirements for Apache and MySQL for Laravel 5.0

Tags: mysql, apache, laravel, laravel-5, requirements

What are the minimal requirements for Apache and MySQL for Laravel 5.0?

I have been able to find out the [requirement for PHP version](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0#server-requirements), which is 

**PHP >= 5.4, PHP < 7**

But I couldn't find the requirements for **Apache** and **MySQL**. Please help!

Comment: No need to worry about apache. For Mysql use >=5.6. If you are using *amp package such as WAMP, LAMP and MAMP latest versions of all packages comes with MySQL 5.7

Comment: Thanks for posting this! It's hard to know if our aging web infrastructure will support anything cool anymore.